Feasibility cuts in outer approximation approach for MINLP
I'm trying to understand feasibility cuts in the context of outer approximation for MINLP problems. Given a MINLP of the following form:
\begin{align}
\mbox{minimize } &c^Ty +f(x)\\
\mbox{s.t. } &g(x) + By \leq 0\\
&Ay\leq a\\
&x\in X;y\in \{0,1\}; f(x)\mbox{ and } g(x) \mbox{convex}
\end{align}
This problem can be equivalently stated as the following MILP:
\begin{align}
\mbox{MP:= minimize } &\alpha\\
\mbox{s.t. } & \alpha \geq c^Ty +f(x^k) + \nabla f(x^k)^T(x-x^k)\\
&g(x^k) + \nabla g(x^k)^T (x-x^k) + By \leq 0\\
&Ay\leq a\\
&x\in X;y\in \{0,1\}; \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
, where the first set of inequalities ($\alpha \geq \dots$) are referred to as the optimality cuts, and the 2nd set of inequalities ($\dots \leq 0$) the feasibility cuts.
In addition, for fixed $y=\bar{y}$ we also define the following 2 non-linear subproblems:
\begin{align}
\mbox{SPO($\bar{y}^k$):= minimize } &c^T\bar{y}^k +f(x)\\
\mbox{s.t. } &g(x) + B\bar{y}^k \leq 0\\
&x\in X
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mbox{SPF($\bar{y}^k$):= minimize } &u\\
\mbox{s.t. } &g(x) + B\bar{y}^k \leq u\\
&x\in X, u\geq 0
\end{align}
Outer approximation algorithm sketch:

Set iteration counter $k=1$, guess initial value $\bar{y}^k$ of the $y$ variables, and define problem MP without any feasibility or optimality cuts.
Solve problem SPO($\bar{y}^k$). If not feasible, go to step 3, else obtain solution $x^k$ and objective value $f^{ub}$, and add both an optimality and a feasibility cut for $x^k$ to MP. Go to step 4.
Solve problem SPF($\bar{y}^k$) and obtain solution $x^k$. Add a feasibility cut for $x^k$ to MP.
Increment $k$. Solve problem MP to obtain solution $\bar{y}^k$ and objective $f^{ub}$. If $f^{ub}-f^{lb} \leq \epsilon$: stop, else go to step 2.

Q1. Most algorithms either add an optimality or a feasibility cut in a single iteration, but not both? I do not quite understand why in step (2), when SPO($\bar{y}^k$) is feasible, we still add a feasibility cut? Is this really necessary to ensure convergence of the algorithm?
Q2. When SPO($\bar{y}^k)$ is infeasible for a given $\bar{y}^k$, we need to add a cut to MP that cuts off this $y$ solution. We therefore first solve SPO($\bar{y}^k)$ to find a solution $x_k$ that has the least amount of constraint violation, and add the corresponding feasiblity cut to MP. I do not understand: (i) why this particular cut cuts off the infeasible $y$, and (ii) why we need the $x_k$ with the least amount of constraint violation for that?
